# Unity injecting dependencies down the call stack

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to get to grips with IoC containers (Unity specifically at the moment), and am having a bit of struggle with the concept of injecting all dependencies up front.

My problem is specifically related to a class that has a constructor parameter that has a value that isn't known when I initially register the types in the container.

Here's a little snippet that should illustrate what I'm talking about.

```
class Class1
{
    IUnityContainer uContainer;

    public Class1()
    {
        uContainer = new UnityContainer();

        uContainer.RegisterType<IRepo, Repo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()));

        Class2 cls2 = uContainer.Resolve<Class2>();

        cls2.DoSomething();

    }
}

class Class2
{
    IRepo _repo;

    public Class2(IRepo p_repo)
    {
        _repo = p_repo;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        IType2 typ2 = new Type2(_repo.SomeDataRetrieved());

        Class3 cls3 = new Class3(_repo, typ2);
    }
}

class Class3
{
    IRepo _repo;
    IType2 _type2;

    public Class3(IRepo p_repo, IType2 p_type2)
    {
        _repo = p_repo;
        _type2 = p_type2;
    }
}
```

I can set up the container in Class1 and have the Repo injected into Class2 using the UnityContainer. In Class2, some lookup against the Repo is done returning an instance of Type2 that is only possible to instantiate in Class2. I then need to pass the Repo to Class3 together with the new object created of Type2.

The problem is twofold:

1. I can't resolve Class3 in Class1 because it can only be instantiated in Class2.
2. I can't register Type2 in the container because it actually has to have a value (not a default one) based on the output of a call in Class2, which is in a different scope from where the Container existed and did the registrations.

As it stands, I can inject the dependancies using the container into Class2, but for Class3 I need to create new instances or using contructor injection from 2 to 3, which then makes me wonder why I'm using the Container then if I have to resort to manual injection anyway.

So, how do I register Class3 in the container so that when I instantiate it, I Inject the singleton of the repo that was registered in the container at the beginning as well as the instance of Type2 that was created in DoSomething.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple things about your approach:

1. The container and registration should occur before being in Class1. If you just wrote it like that as an exemple, and that in your actual code, it's in the `program`, or equivalent, disregard this comment.
2. You should look into the factories with Unity. For example, when constructing Class2, you could pass a `Func<IType2, Class3>` to it's constructor, and from within Class2, call that factory to get the `Class3` instance. Here is an example :

```
container.RegisterType<Func<Type2, Class3>>(
    new InjectionFactory(c =>
    new Func<Type2, Class3>(type2 =>
    c.Resolve<Class3>(
        new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter<IRepo>(),
            type2)))));
```

*Note: Haven't tested **that** code, but I've done something similar.*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tipx's answer, when doing dependency injection, you don't want your classes to directly create other classes.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    IType2 typ2 = new Type2(_repo.SomeDataRetrieved());
    Class3 cls3 = new Class3(_repo, typ2);
}
```

This ties `class2` to `Type2` and `Class3`, which might be ok if those three are that close that none one of them can be exchanged, but normally at some point in time you want to swap out `Type2` for `OverchargedType2Plus` or `Type2Mock`. And that's what the abstract factory is for: give `Class2` something that can create `Type2`s.

```
interface IType2Factory
{
     IType2 Create( Data theData );
}

class Type2Type2Factory : IType2Factory
{
     public IType2 Create( Data theData ) => new Type2( theData );
}
```

(If `Type2` needs further dependencies, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768318/how-better-to-resolve-dependencies-in-object-created-by-factory/39788267#39788267))

And then, give the `IType2Factory`to `Class2`:

```
class Class2
{
    private readonly IRepo _repo;
    private readonly IType2Factory _type2Factory;

    public Class2( IRepo repo, IType2Factory type2Factory )
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _type2Factory = type2Factory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var typ2 = _type2Factory.Create( _repo.SomeDataRetrieved() );
    }
}
```

And when the day comes and you need `OverchargedType2Plus`, create an `IType2Factory` implementation and register that instead and watch `Class2` work with the new `Type2` variant without even knowning it exists, let alone requiring any changes.

Comment: Yeah, I first had a section about "You should look into using interfaces", but since he used IType2, I figured the omission of other Interfaces was just him writing a quick example.

Comment: Fair enough, I mainly wanted to give an alternative to the factory defined in the registration. To me, manually coding the factory has three advantages: the registration is much simpler and the definition of the factory and the product can be much closer together, to the point where the product is a private nested class of the factory, and most important, you get compile-time checking for your factory (the injection factory will at runtime if the product's constructor changes)...

Comment: Taken a while for me to get back to this problem. 2 points, I am using interfaces wherever I can and I am using factories, but for simpler tasks, didn't think about using the factory that way. This definitely helps the thought processes. I haven't resolved the issue just yet, but this definitely looks like the right direction to be going to get it working properly. Thanks to the both of you for the input.