# How to inject only one object to constructor using unity DI

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unity-container

How to inject only one object to constructor using Unity DI.
Example:

```
public class MyClass{

public MyClass(ILog logger, IProvider provider, IResolver resolver, ItemTypeEnum itemType)
{
   //.... initializing everything
}

public ItemTypeEnum ItemType { get; set;}

//....methods where I will use this itemKind
}
```

I want to inject only itemType value to the constructor, to use this itemType in implementation depends of value of this enum.

Comment: I have to ask, why would you want to only inject one of those dependencies?

Comment: If you have to ask this question, it is a sign that `MyClass` is doing more than one responsibility, and is therefore a violation of the Single Responsibility Principal.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I might have gotten the question wrong, but to me it only makes sense to inject all dependencies *but* `itemType`, not the other way round.

The easiest option is to create a `MyClassFactory` with a `CreateMyClass( ItemTypeEnum itemType )` method. Details see [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768318/how-better-to-resolve-dependencies-in-object-created-by-factory/39788267#39788267)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InjectionConstructor` and provide parameter during the resolution. The example is as following:

```
container.RegisterType<ILog, Log>();
container.RegisterType<IResolver, Resolver>();
container.RegisterType<IProvider, Provider>();
container.RegisterType<MyClass>(new InjectionConstructor(
    new ResolvedParameter<ILog>(),
    new ResolvedParameter<IProvider>(),
    new ResolvedParameter<IResolver>(),
    typeof(ItemTypeEnum)));                

MyClass mc = container.Resolve<MyClass>(new ParameterOverride("itemType", ItemTypeEnum.Value));
```