# How to inject new instance at run time in Prism?

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

I'm using Prism 7.1 for WPF application.
I tried to use built-in IOC(Unity) but I don't know how I can resolve new instance at run time maybe from method or from containerProvider. But it seems IContainerProvider is not available to be injected in my view model. Do I have any option?

I want to do this to reload my database context. I was told that creating new context is the easiest among others.

```
    public class ProjectViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private UnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        private IContainerProvider containerProvider;
        private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
        #region Constructor
        public ProjectViewModel(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, IContainerProvider cp, IEventAggregator ea)
        {
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            containerProvider = cp;
            eventAggregator = ea;
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<SendReloadDataEvents>().Subscribe(Reload);
            Reload();
        }
        #endregion

        private void Reload()
        {
            this.unitOfWork = containerProvider.Resolve<UnitOfWork>();
            Projects = new ObservableCollection<Projects>(unitOfWork.ProjectRepo.GetAll());
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customers>(unitOfWork.CustomerRepo.Find(x => x.Projects.Count > 0));
            SelectedProjectType = null;
        }
//Other logic continues
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting the container is an anti-pattern, so we'll try to avoid that and inject a factory instead. In fact, `IContainerProvider` and `IContainerRegistry` aren't registered themselves for this reason, to make it impossible to inject them.

A factory is easy though:

```
public class ProjectViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private UnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private Func<UnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory;
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    #region Constructor
    public ProjectViewModel(Func<UnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory, IEventAggregator ea) // no need to inject a unit of work
    {
        _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
        eventAggregator = ea;
        ea.GetEvent<SendReloadDataEvents>().Subscribe(Reload); // prefer the parameter
        Reload();
    }
    #endregion

    private void Reload()
    {
        this.unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory(); // create a new one here (the container does the work but is hidden)
        Projects = new ObservableCollection<Projects>(unitOfWork.ProjectRepo.GetAll()); // I'd rather update the existing collection
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customers>(unitOfWork.CustomerRepo.Find(x => x.Projects.Count > 0)); // same here, or probably, it could just be IEnumerable
        SelectedProjectType = null;
    }
//Other logic continues
}
```

Note that this `Func<>` factory is ok only for the most simple cases. If you need parameters passed into the product constructor, you have to code it yourself as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768318/how-better-to-resolve-dependencies-in-object-created-by-factory/39788267#39788267). Also note how the container never shows up anywhere (except where it's configured), making your code dependent on the container is just unnecessary and will make tests more ugly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not familiar with Func factory. How can I register Func<> factory in container, Prism? Normally we use Method "containerRegistry.Register<TYPE>();". I don't think I can put Func instead of class...

Comment: Unity creates the `Func<>` automatically. Just register your type and inject the `Func` and you get a deferred `Resolve`, works with interfaces, too, of course, i.e. `containerRegistry.Register<ISomething,TheImplementation>();` -> `public Consumer( Func<ISomething> injectedFactory)`

Comment: Okay. It's great. Now I know how it works. Thank you so much, Haukinger. Have a great day.