# How do I specify constructor parameters in my dependency injection container in Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, prism-7

How do I inject constructor parameters in my dependencies that I configure using Prism?

I overrode `RegisterTypes` to register my dependencies like this:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
   protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
   {
      containerRegistry.Register<IMyService, MyService>();        
   }
}
```

However, `MyService` has some constructor parameters that I need to be able to pass in.  I want to be able to pass constructor parameters to `MyService`, similar to how I would do it like this in Unity.

```
containerRegistry.Register<IMyService, MyService>(
   new InjectionConstructor("param1", "param2"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a handcoded `IMyServiceFactory`. That can pass your parameters *and* potential dependencies of the service.

```
public interface IMyServiceFactory
{
    IMyService CreateMyService();
}

internal class MyServiceFactory : IMyServiceFactory
{
    public IMyService CreateMyService() => new MyService( "param1", "param2" );
}
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768318/how-better-to-resolve-dependencies-in-object-created-by-factory/39788267#39788267), too.

Comment: Blegh, I was hoping there was a way to do this without factories, but I guess I'm out of luck.  I like your suggestion of making the factory `internal`.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Regarding the `internal` you can go even more hardcore  and make the product a private class within the factory (if your testing requirements permit).

Comment: Regarding the factory in itself, see it as a clear sign for everyone that says "If you use this, the product is yours. It's your responsibility to dispose it when you're done with it." I've moved to injecting `Func<Something>` instead of `Something` (with transient lifetime) because it makes clear who disposes (the consumer or the container).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to register an instance:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(new MyService("param1", "param2"));
```

reference: [Registering Types with Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/registering-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and it works:

```
containerRegistry.Register<IMyService>(() => new MyService("param1", "param2"));
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMyService>(() => new MyService("param1", "param2"));

containerRegistry.Register(typeof(IMyService), () => new MyService("param1", "param2")); 
containerRegistry.RegisteSingleton(typeof(IMyService), () => new MyService("param1", "param2"));
```